# how can I filter the continuous days in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my scenario, I want find the users who had continuously login our website equal or greater than 3 days.
For example:

```
{"login_time":"2018-01-01T18:19:07.982Z", "user_id":123}
{"login_time":"2018-01-01T08:30:07.982Z", "user_id":456}
{"login_time":"2018-01-02T09:39:07.982Z", "user_id":123}
{"login_time":"2018-01-03T08:20:07.982Z", "user_id":123}
{"login_time":"2018-01-03T08:20:07.982Z", "user_id":456}
```

So, the user_id:123 has been continuously login for 3 days and user_id:456 has been continuously login for 1 day, I wish I can drop the user_id:456 when Elasticsearch returns.

This is my ES JSON:

```
GET event-tracking/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "login_by_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "login_time",
        "interval": "day"
      }, 
      "aggs": {
        "user_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "user_id",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And response:

```
"aggregations": {
    "login_by_day": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1514764800000,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "user_id": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": 123,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": 456,
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1514851200000,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "user_id": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": 123,
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2018-01-03T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1514937600000,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "user_id": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": 123,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": 456,
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Then, I have to write some code to filter the result. My question is how can I use ES JSON to reach it without any code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather then `date_histogram` maybe you should try `min_doc_count`

Comment: I tired, but it will not arrange by days, and that's not what I need. thanks any way.